# Display a custom text at the top of order grid

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, custom, ajax, order-grid

I have saved AWB no.s in my database and it is alloted according to a particular algorithm.
I have specified a range of AWB no.s. From my order grid, I select the orders and allot AWB no.s to them.

I want to display the `limit` attribute of the AWB table in my orders grid.

How can I do this ?

Comment: If you have order Id reference in your AWB table, you can get column using join based on order ID.